# Global Secondary Indexes in AppSync Schemas (with DynamoDB)

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, apollo, aws-appsync

I am creating my AppSync GraphQL schema (with DynamoDB). Here is my current model:

```
input AMPLIFY {
  globalAuthRule: AuthRule = { allow: public }
} # FOR TESTING ONLY!
type Post
  @model {
  id: ID! @primaryKey(sortKeyFields: ["sk"])
  sk: String!
  title: String!
  featuredPost: String
}
```

On the base table i want `id` to be the primary key with the sort key being `sk`, as seen.

However, I want a global secondary index with the primary key being `featuredPost` and sort key being `title`.

- How would I add this to the schema? (AI answers are very inconsistent, and I cant find anything in the AWS Docs)
- Does any reference to a GSI even need to be added to the schema?

Answer (score 1):

You add the index using the console.

Then in your resolver you explicitly tell it which index to use to make that request. Your schema remains unchanged.

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52791010/aws-appsync-adding-global-secondary-index-to-dynamodb-and-pagination-using-gsi)

Comment: Is there anywhere in the docs that details how to tell the resolver which index to make the request to? As my resolvers were being autogenerated (I will need to learn how to make that change). The linked stackoverflow post is quite specific to their case and was five years ago (if anything has changed since).